# How can I tell in a script, which AzureAD domain a machine is joined to, and which groups it is in, locally on the machine?

Tags: windows-10, script, azure-activedirectory

I have existing PowerShell and VBScript scripts to tell me things like which AD domain and forest a machine is joined to, which OU it resides in, which site it considers itself to be in, etc. And I can get this information locally on the machine, without having to touch the network.

How can I get the same information for an Enta /AzureAD domain? I've looked in *HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Enrollments*, but not found anything useful, and found nothing in the wider registry. Is this information retained/cached locally anywhere I can read it?

Comment: We are always glad to help, but a question of this nature would probably be much more appropriate at [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/)

Comment: What research have you done and what have you tried while attempting to solve this? You say you've looked through the registry, but have you searched online for this? I would guess the computer doesn't cache a list of the groups it is a member of, but it should know the domain, and possibly its CN value.

Answer (score 0):

Depends what you want to do with it, but I use something that starts like this(Powershell);

```
$wshShell = New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell
$objExec = $wshShell.Exec("powershell -command (whoami /FQDN).Split('=')[1].Split(' ')[0]")

$strUserName = $objExec.StdOut.ReadAll().Trim()
$strGroupName = $wshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%USERDOMAIN%")
$strComputerName = $wshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%COMPUTERNAME%")
```